# Kubernetes setup in Redhat Linux - The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, redhat, rhel

I am using the following link to setup kubernetes environment and run a containers in kubernetes.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/getting_started_with_kubernetes/get_started_orchestrating_containers_with_kubernetes

However,when I run "kubectl create -f db-service.yaml" as mentioned in section 1.3.3 - step 5, am getting "**The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?**".

Can you help if am missing anything, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think that this is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on stackoverflow?

Comment: Looks like kubernetes is not running. What does `ss -tulnp | grep -E "(kube)|(etcd)" ` give?

Comment: tcp   LISTEN  0   128   127.0.0.1:10248   *:*   users:(("kubelet",pid=66113,fd=10))
tcp   LISTEN  0   128   127.0.0.1:10249   *:*   users:(("kube-proxy",pid=66059,fd=9))
tcp   LISTEN  0   128   127.0.0.1:10250   *:*   users:(("kubelet",pid=66113,fd=14))
tcp   LISTEN  0   128   127.0.0.1:2379    *:*   users:(("etcd",pid=65696,fd=6))
tcp   LISTEN  0   128   127.0.0.1:2380    *:*   users:(("etcd",pid=65696,fd=5))
tcp   LISTEN  0   128   127.0.0.1:10255   *:*   users:(("kubelet",pid=66113,fd=13))
tcp   LISTEN  0   128   :::4194           :::*  users:(("kubelet",pid=66113,fd=9))

Comment: @dlmeetei, this is the output of ss -tulnp | grep -E "(kube)|(etcd)"

Comment: ok, They are not listening at port 8080, That explains the issue.